# Azure Service Bus Amqp token issue

Tags: azure, kotlin, azureservicebus, quarkus, azure-aks

I'm using Azure Service Bus, and Managed ID to authenticate to it. I'm using Kotlin and Quarkus, in an AKS environment.

Now my issue is that when I deploy my code I get the following error:

```
2022-04-03 09:34:20,287 ERROR [com.azu.cor.amq.imp.ActiveClientTokenManager] (reactor-executor-2) 
Error occurred while refreshing token that is not retriable. Not scheduling refresh task. Use ActiveClientTokenManager.authorize() to 
schedule task again.
period >= 0 required but it was -1484002855000000000
```

It seems there's something wrong with the refresh token, but I can't really figure out what it is.

I'm creating my Service Bus processor client using a producer method like this:

```
    @Produces
    @Singleton
    fun serviceBusProducerClientBuilder(): ServiceBusProcessorClientBuilder = ServiceBusClientBuilder()
        .credential(messagingConfig.namespace(), tokenCredential)
        .transportType(AmqpTransportType.AMQP_WEB_SOCKETS)
        .processor()
        .topicName(messagingConfig.topics().captureResults())
        .subscriptionName(messagingConfig.subscription())
```

Now I can add a method called ".retryOptions()" and feed it some retry options, but I'm not sure if that's the issue here.

Does anyone know what I should look for?